# Fast way to find exponential of a matrix dot product where one of them is diagonal

Tags: matrices, exponentiation, diagonalization

Suppose $Q$ is a dot product of diagonal matrix A and matrix B:
$$
Q=A\cdot B=
\left(
        \begin{matrix}
        a_1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
        0 & a_2 & \cdots & 0 \\
        \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
        0 & 0 & \cdots & a_n
        \end{matrix} 
\right)
\cdot
\left(
        \begin{matrix}
        b_{11} & b_{12} & \cdots & b_{1n} \\
        b_{21} & b_{22} & \cdots & b_{2n} \\
        \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
        b_{n1} & b_{n2} & \cdots & b_{nn}
        \end{matrix} 
\right),
$$
$a_i>0$, $b_{ij}>0$ if $i\neq j$, $b_{ii}=-\sum_{j\neq i}{b_{ij}}$.

Let's assume that B is diagonalizable, so $B=P D  P^{-1}$, where $D$ is diagonal matrix.

Can we easily compute $e^Q$ if we have computed already $P$, $D$ and $e^B$? Or we have to perform Jordan decomposition for every new matrix $A$?

P.S. AFAIU it is possible to find $e^{Qt}$ where $t$ is scalar: $e^{Qt}=P e^{Dt} P^{-1}$. So I was wondering whether the same is possible with diagonal matrix.